# Indesign Align doesn't align properly

Tags: adobe-indesign

Simply when I use the Distribute Horizontal centers option within the Align panel one image will be pushed further to the left or right and the three or any other images won't be aligned equally apart. This has been driving me crazy, it only happens with certain images as in some images will distribute fine, anyone had this problem or know how to fix it?

[image: Manual equal alignment]

[image: Wrong alignment by using the Distribute Horizontal centers tool]

Comment: Does the centre of the pictures are the same as centre of picture box?

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Yep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Adobe don't think the way you (we) do. Distribution part should be, according to them, used with the "use spacing" or "align to".
Otherwise (as I tried) if objects are not symmetrically spread out (as in your example) it give strange results.
To have even distribution in the selection the Anatomy of Murder poster should be the middle one.

Answer (score 6):

Do you want to align the images or distribute the space between them equally?

If what you want is distribute the space see in the image the best option to do it. I never 'distribute objects' I always 'distribute spacing' because different objects with different sizes will end up making different spacing.

I just don't use that tool. Sadly in inDesign they have that in the top bar but not the distribute spacing one. So you will have to go to Window > Objects & Layout > Align and then use it directly from the full Align box. You can place the Align box in a fixed position on the side bar just in case you have some more objects and spaces to sort out.

[image: 1]]

Hope this helps.